ことには usage in this sentence?
"もう――戻りますよ" 光は踵を返した。
部署に戻ることにはお互い落ち着いて、この感情は抑え込まれているのだろうけれど.
Hikari says "Let's go back"
But then I don't understand what the narration is implying? What is this usage of ことには? "in order to"?
The characters had a fight and now they decided to go back at their work post.

Please double check the original. Are you sure that you have copied the sentence correctly?  It should be 「部署に戻るころには」. (「~~[頃]{ころ}には」= "by the time~~") 「部署に戻ることにはお互い落ち着いて、この感情は抑え込まれているのだろう...」 doesn't make much sense.

As a side note, conditional 「～ことには」"unless~~" should be used with a negative phrase, as in 「部署に戻らないことには、仕事にならない。」 . For more on 「～ことには」, see here, here.

ことには corresponds here to "by the time" the preceding action is done, so:
By the time they return to their office...
It's like a condition for what follows. Here you can find similar expressions.
